# MySQL: How to reset or change the MySQL root password?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

How do I change the MySQL root password and username in ubuntu server?  Do I need to stop the mysql service before setting any changes?

I have a phpmyadmin setup as well, will phpmyadmin get updated automatically?

Comment: If you don't need the data you can "reset" the password by removing mysql in its entirety: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853004/removing-mysql-5-5-completely/11869352#11869352 then installing it again (it will prompt you for the "new" root password) FWIW :)

Comment: Do you know the MySQL root password?

Comment: in mysql-server-5.7 these methods dont work. use 'sudo' without password as mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/a/848504

Comment: Tip: sort by "oldest" and then look at the newest answers. The most upvoted answers don't work in newer versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 309, accepted):

Set / change / reset the MySQL root password on Ubuntu Linux. Enter the following lines in your terminal.

1. Stop the MySQL Server: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
2. (*In some cases, if `/var/run/mysqld` doesn't exist, you have to create it at first: `sudo mkdir -v /var/run/mysqld && sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld`*
3. Start the `mysqld` configuration: `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &`
4. Login to MySQL as root: `mysql -u root mysql`
5. Replace `YOURNEWPASSWORD` with your new password:

**For MySQL < 8.0**

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If your MySQL uses new auth plugin, you will need to use: `update user set plugin="mysql_native_password" where User='root';` before flushing privileges.

> Note: on some versions, if `password` column doesn't exist, you may want to try:
> `UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE user='root';`

**Note: This method is not regarded as the most secure way of resetting the password, however, it works.**

**For MySQL >= 8.0**

```sql
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOURNEWPASSWORD';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

## Last step:

As noted in comments by @lambart, you might need to kill the temporary  password-less mysql process that you started, i.e. `sudo killall -9 mysqld` and then start normal daemon: `sudo service mysql start`

References:

1. [Set / Change / Reset the MySQL root password on Ubuntu Linux](http://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password/)
2. [How to Reset the Root Password (v5.6)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html)
3. [How to Reset the Root Password (v8.0)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: Of course, after this point you'll need to kill the temporary, password-less server process that you started in step 2. maybe use `sudo killall -9 mysqld`? and then `sudo service mysql start` to restart the normal daemon...

Comment: The method in this answer is only needed for resetting a MySQL root password that you don't know [[source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)]. If you know it, the `SET PASSWORD` MySQL instruction is for you.

Comment: Can it not be done only by logging in phpMyAdmin as a root user and then executing these SQLs?
`UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';`
`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: i followed till 3rd step and i get Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)  when i login thru root

Comment: Doesn't work on 5.7. Look at the Anvesh's answer instead.

Comment: in some cases, you also need to run `mkdir /var/run/mysqld` and `chown mysql: /var/run/mysqld` between steps 1 and 2

Comment: Probably this just will works on MySQL 5.7.6 and later. To reset in earlier versions of Mysql: SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');

Comment: Try to verify your SA credentials.

Comment: step 3 did not work for me with Ubuntu 18.04. I just logged in using **sudo mysql**

Comment: All these solutions failed in Ubuntu 18.04 and MySQL 5.7.25 I think because they missed `UPDATE user SET plugin="mysql_native_password" WHERE User='root';` after setting the password. Follow details here... https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-reset-root-mysql-password-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Correct answer but before 3rd step run:  sudo service mysql start

Comment: Soyab Badi> does not help "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: @JiříDoubravský what step?

Comment: Note that in some versions both the "Password" column and the "authentication_string" columns exist. Updating them both does the trick.

Comment: If `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables` doesn't work, check the error logs: `tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log` (it's either you didn't stop the existing process or didn't create `/var/run/mysqld` directory).

Comment: Step 3: How are you supposed to connect to MySQL which is stopped in Step 1?

Comment: check comment @Atul.:)

Comment: This answer is dated 2013.  I fixed today with   `sudo mysql` (read  Amir's answer)

Comment: I also had to change `plugin` to: `mysql_native_password`

Comment: For anybody struggling to get these statements to execute. The PASSWORD() function was deprecated in more recent versions of mysql, so you will need to do something like this, for example SHA1:

`UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = SHA1('MYSECRETPASSWORD') WHERE User = 'root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: This solution doesn't work, because you don't have rights for mysql.service. The answer below skip-grant-tables worked for me. This shouldn't be the correct answer.

Comment: step 4.    ```mysql -u root mysql```
needed    ```sudo```

Comment: @Sushivam I've updated answer, so now it has correct step numbers.

Comment: additionally, it will show `The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement` in MySQL 8, so you need to flush privileges at first.

Comment: Works on MySQL 8.0.32 running on Ubuntu 22.

Answer (score 180):

The only method that worked for me is the one described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472811/unable-to-login-as-root-after-mysql-service-restart) (I am running ubuntu 14.04). For the sake of clarity, these are the steps I followed:

1. `sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
2. Add the following lines at the end:

   ```
   [mysqld]

   skip-grant-tables
   ```
3. `sudo service mysql restart`
4. `mysql -u root`
5. `use mysql`
6. `select * from mysql.user where user = 'root';` - Look at the top to determine whether the password column is called
   *password* or *authentication_string*
7. `UPDATE mysql.user set *password_field from above* = PASSWORD('your_new_password') where user = 'root' and host = 'localhost';` - Use the proper password column from above
8. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
9. `exit`
10. `sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
11. **Remove the lines added in step 2** if you want to keep your security standards.
12. `sudo service mysql restart`

For reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Finally, this worked for me!  I'm running MySQL 5.7.18 on Ubuntu 16.04.  I tried dpkg-reconfigure, Anvesh's answer, Christian Mark's answer, and even the instructions on MySQL's help page.

Comment: I had to run 
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root'; 

instead for line 5.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me. I have Ubuntu 17.04 and mysql 5.7

Comment: In point 6 you have to add `user` should be this way `select * from mysql.user where user = 'root';`

Comment: Sad this does not work for me mysql 5.7.22 ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Ubuntu 18.04, mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24

Comment: Works here in Ubuntu 18.04 too

Comment: Everything was working as expected. But when trying to login it's saying Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: The function `PASSWORD` doesn't exist in newer versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 101):

The official and easy way to reset the root password on an ubuntu server...

If you are on 16.04, 14.04, 12.04:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

If you are on 10.04:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1
```

If you are not sure which mysql-server version is installed you can try:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql-server
```

**Updated notes for mysql-server-5.7**

Note that if you are using mysql-server-5.7 you can not use the easier dpkg-reconfigure method shown above.

If you know the password, login and run this:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('my-new-password') WHERE USER='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Alternatively, you can use the following:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

This will ask you a series of questions about securing your installation (highly recommended), including if you want to provide a new root password.

If you do NOT know the root password, [refer to this Ubuntu-centric write up on the process](https://askubuntu.com/a/766908/53517).

See for more info:

https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/mysql.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/mysql.html

Comment: Works even when you lost the original MySQL root password – nice.

Comment: Works with `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu`

Comment: Worked with mysql v 5.0 as well... `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.0`

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7 not working for Ubuntu 18.04 for reset root password. Any other alternate?

Comment: Ubuntu: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7; sudo mysql_secure_installation`

Comment: @user12345 If I have data in databases, Can I use this `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7` command ? it will just reconfigure root or data will be lost?

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya No guarantee, however `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7` has never caused me any data loss or changed data in my own databases. [I would not expect any data loss](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299366/reconfigure-mysql-question). However make a server snapshot if you can. You can [backup MySQL files with caveats](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/create-physical-backups-of-your-mariadb-or-mysql-databases/). Be sure to [understand the risks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482491/is-copying-var-lib-mysql-a-good-alterntive-to-mysqldump).

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL don't have the `PASSWORD` function.

Answer (score 89):

What worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04, mysql 5.7):

Stop MySQL

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Make MySQL service directory.

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
```

Give MySQL user permission to write to the service directory.

```
sudo chown mysql: /var/run/mysqld
```

Start MySQL manually, without permission checks or networking.

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

On another console, log in without a password.

```
mysql -uroot mysql
```

Then:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
EXIT;
```

Turn off MySQL.

```
sudo mysqladmin -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock shutdown
```

Start the MySQL service normally.

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: The other ways did not work for me but this one (thanks!), or you can also go here http://rricketts.com/reset-root-password-mysql-5-7-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

Comment: Very useful ! In my specific case (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), I had to replace the host '%' to 'localhost'

Comment: This didn't work in ubuntu 18.04. But it worked with this little change described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53385753/1591143

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL do not support the `PASSWORD` function.

Answer (score 83):

At first run this command:

```
sudo mysql
```

and then you should check which authentication method of your MySQL user accounts use.So run this command

```
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

now you can see something like this already :

```
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host      |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| root             |                                           | auth_socket           | localhost |
| mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | *CC744277A401A7D25BE1CA89AFF17BF607F876FF | mysql_native_password | localhost |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

in the table that is in the above , you can see that all of your mysql users accounts status & if you have set a password for root account before you see `mysql_native_password` in plugin column instead `auth_socket`.
All in all for change your root password you should run :

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Be sure to change password to a strong password of your choosing.
Then for reload your server to put your new changes into effect run this;

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

So again check the authentication methods which has employed by your mysql , by this command:

```
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

and now the output is :

```
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host      |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| root             | *3636DACC8616D997782ADD0839F92C1571D6D78F | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | *CC744277A401A7D25BE1CA89AFF17BF607F876FF | mysql_native_password | localhost |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

as you can see in the grant table your root account has `mysql_native_password`
.
now you can exit MYSQL shell

```
exit;
```

That's it.just you should restart mysql by `sudo service mysql restart`.
Now you can login to mysql as a root account with your password easily.

Comment: I think this is from DigitalOcean, which was the only solution worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 running on Virtual Box

Comment: Works better than charm! It worked perfectly on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 80):

I am sharing the step by step final solution to reset a MySQL password in Linux 
Ubuntu.

**[Reference taken from blog (dbrnd.com)](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/08/reset-mysql-root-password-ubuntu/)**

Step 1:
Stop MySQL Service.

```
sudo stop mysql
```

Step 2:
Kill all running mysqld.

```
sudo killall -9 mysqld
```

Step 3:
Starting mysqld in Safe mode.

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

Step 4:
Start mysql client

```
mysql -u root
```

Step 5:
After successful login, please execute this command to change any password.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Step 6:
You can update mysql root password .

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
```

**Note**: On MySQL 5.7, column `Password` is called `authentication_string`.

Step 7:
Please execute this command.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Indeed. Also, it is closer to the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html). In case you run into this: "ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded”, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879448/mysql-fails-on-mysql-error-1524-hy000-plugin-auth-socket-is-not-loaded

Comment: I also had to change mysql.user.plugin from 'auth_socket' to 'mysql_native_password' for my root user with host of 'localhost'.

Comment: I had to use "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop" to stop the service and "UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';" to update the password

Comment: authenticated _string helped

Answer (score 47):

I faced problems with ubuntu 18.04 and mysql 5.7, this is the solution

Try restart mysql-server before execution the comands

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

MYSQL-SERVER >= 5.7

```
sudo mysql -uroot -p
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('YOUR_PASSWORD') WHERE User='root';
UPDATE user SET plugin="mysql_native_password";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit;
```

MYSQL-SERVER < 5.7

```
sudo mysql -uroot -p
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('YOUR_PASSWORD') WHERE User='root';
UPDATE user SET plugin="mysql_native_password";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm also running Ubuntu 18.04 here and the `MYSQL-SERVER >= 5.7` version was the only thing that actually solved the problem

Comment: This is the one that worked for in Ubuntu 18.04 mysql installation. `MYSQL-SERVER >= 5.7` version to be precise.

Comment: UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('YOUR_PASSWORD') WHERE User='root';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('YOUR_PASSWORD') WHERE User='root'' at line 1

Comment: Thanks，I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and the MYSQL-SERVER = 5.7， it works for me

Answer (score 36):

**Change the MySQL root password.**

This method exposes the password to the command-line history, these commands should be run as root.

1. Login through mysql command line tool:

   ```
   mysql -uroot -poldpassword
   ```
2. Run this command:

   ```
   SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpassword');
   ```

or

2. Run this command, which sets a password for the current user ('root' for this case) :

   > SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('newpassword');

Comment: this is Quick way

Answer (score 15):

1. Stop MySQL
   **sudo service mysql stop**
2. Make MySQL service directory.
   **sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld**
3. Give MySQL user permission to write to the service directory.
   **sudo chown mysql: /var/run/mysqld**
4. Start MySQL manually, without permission checks or networking.
   **sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &**

5.Log in without a password.
**mysql -uroot mysql**

6.Update the password for the root user.

**UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='%';**
EXIT;

7. Turn off MySQL.
   **sudo mysqladmin -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock shutdown**
8. Start the MySQL service normally.
   **sudo service mysql start**

Comment: Hi, this answer works for me, but I had to use another command: 
``UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('solutionclub3@*^G'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';`` without ``AND Host='%'``. Thanks!

Comment: This also worked for me!

Answer (score 15):

In my case this option helped : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49610152/13760371
Thank you, Rahul.

except for the following moment, when I try entered command:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='%';
```

the console issued a warning:

```
1681 'password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
```

cured with this command:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('NEWPASSWORD'))))), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
```

MySQL version 5.7.X

My variant:

```
1. > sudo service mysql stop
2. > sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
3. > sudo chown mysql: /var/run/mysqld
4. > sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
5. > mysql -uroot mysql
6. > UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('NEWPASSWORD'))))), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
7. > \q;
8. > sudo mysqladmin -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock shutdown
9. > sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me for MySQL 8.0 on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Ok, Flimm. Happy to help.

Comment: This worked for me. but in first step mysql stop does not worked for me I have to use `mysqladmin shutdown` and steps 2 and 3 did not need for me because the file existed.

Answer (score 13):

If you would like to change the MySQL root password, in a terminal enter:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5`

The MySQL daemon will be stopped, and you will be prompted to enter a new password.

Comment: This is a much better way to do it. I was unable to run the previous commands because of some mysql error...

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7` on Ubuntu 16.04, it didn't prompt to enter a new password.

Comment: If it says `mysql-server is broken or not fully installed`, one can use `sudo apt purge mysql*` and `sudo apt install mysql-server`

Comment: @user2206324 If I have data in databases, Can I use this sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5 command ? it will just reconfigure root or data will be lost?

Answer (score 13):

This  works like charm I did it for Ubuntu 16.04.
Full credit to below link as I got it from there. 
[https://coderwall.com/p/j9btlg/reset-the-mysql-5-7-root-password-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts][1]

Stop MySQL

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Make MySQL service directory.
    sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld

Give MySQL user permission to write to the service directory.

```
sudo chown mysql: /var/run/mysqld
```

Start MySQL manually, without permission checks or networking.

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

Log in without a password.

```
mysql -uroot mysql
```

Update the password for the root user.
make sure at atleast root account gets updated by the below query.
make some selection and check the existing values if you like

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET 
authentication_string=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD'), 
plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
EXIT;
```

Turn off MySQL.

```
sudo mysqladmin -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock shutdown
```

Start the MySQL service normally.

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 12):

This solution belongs to the previous version of MySQL.
By logging in to MySQL using socket authentication, you can do it.

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

Then the following command could be run.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Details are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40291452/596021) .

Comment: I couldn't login as **`sudo mysql -u root`** but I was able to do it as **`sudo mysql`** and run the `ALTER USER` command.

Comment: I was getting this error: "Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements". I was able to correct this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094873/9073437 . After setting a modified password policy, everything worked fine.

Comment: ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Answer (score 10):

This is the solution for me. I work at Ubuntu 18.04:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46076838/2400373

But is important this change in the last step:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
```

Comment: Gosh! Thanks a lot! This is the only way that was working in my case. Forget about that stupid secure installation script as it kept my freshly installed 5.7 wide open to users without ever asking for a password ... if Linux/Ubuntu is for safety-aware users why is it this hard to protect a crucial application like MySQL server?

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL don't support the `PASSWORD` function.

Answer (score 8):

For Ubuntu 18.04 and mysql version 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22 follow the below step to reset the mysql password.

## Step 1

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
```

## Step 2

```
sudo systemctl edit mysql
```

This command will open a new file in the nano editor, which you'll use to edit MySQL's service overrides. These change the default service parameters for MySQL. This file will be empty, so add the following content:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

## Step 3

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

## Step 4

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

## Step 5

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

## Step 6

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('new_password') WHEREuser = 'root';
```

## Step 7

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin ='mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'root';
```

## Step 8

```
sudo systemctl revert mysql
```

and finally

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Now enjoy

Comment: I think you missed content on step 2. It's incomplete.

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL don't support the `PASSWORD` function.

Answer (score 7):

Echoing rogerdpack's comment: if you don't know the MySQL root password and you don't care about MySQL data/settings, you can reinstall it and reset the root's password as follows:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server mysql-client
```

During the installation, you can choose the root's password:

[image]

Comment: I wish I had started here instead of wasting an hour banging my head at trying to reset the password.

Answer (score 5):

If you know your current password, you don't have to stop mysql server.
Open the ubuntu terminal.
Login to mysql using:

```
mysql - username -p
```

Then type your password.
This will take you into the mysql console.
Inside the console, type:

```
> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

Then flush privileges using:

```
> flush privileges;
```

Then you are all done.

Comment: ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Answer (score 3):

You don't need all this. Simply log in:

`mysql -u root -p`

Then change the current user's password as the `mysql>` prompt:

```
mysql> set password=password('the_new_password');
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Comment: This is a simplest way! It working for me with mysql 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.17.10.1

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL don't support the `PASSWORD` function.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers on this topic are outdated; two major changes have occurred in MySQL up until the writing of this answer:

1- the 'Password' field in the user table has been replaced by 'authentication_string' column.

2- the 'Password' encryption function : PASSWORD("of some text") is deprecated.

Please refer to this link for further [information:dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Answer (score 3):

1.Open nano / vim to create a file with the following content and Save file as `~/mysql-pwd`

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NEWPASSWORD';
```

2. Stop mysql `sudo systemctl stop mysql`
3. Run `sudo mysqld -init-file=~/mysql-pwd`
4. Restart mysql `sudo systemctl start mysql`
5. Now login `mysql -u root -p`. password will be your `NEWPASSWORD`

Answer (score 3):

The steps below worked for me. I'm using MySQL 8.* on Ubuntu

1. Stop MySQL service and check status to confirm the service stopped

> ```
> sudo systemctl stop mysql
> sudo systemctl status mysql
> ```

2. Edit the systemd config file so you can access MySQL without permission check

   `sudo systemctl edit mysql`
3. Copy and paste the following 3 lines

> ```
> [Service]
>
> ExecStart=
>
> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
> ```

After pasting the lines **CTRL+0** to save and then **CTRL+X** to exit

4. Reload mysql service and start it (starts the service with --skip-grant-table)

> ```
> sudo systemctl daemon-reload
> sudo systemctl start mysql
> ```

5.Now connect to MySQL server without password

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

6.Load the grant tables by running

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

7. Reset the root password

> mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH
> mysql_native_password BY 'YourPasswordHere';

8. Close the mysql connection

> mysql> exit

9. Revert the modification done on the mysql systemd file

> sudo systemctl revert mysql

10. Reload the mysql daemon for changes to take place.

> sudo systemctl daemon-reload

11. Lastly restart the MySQL service

> sudo systemctl restart mysql

Now connect to mysql with the new password set in step 7

You can visit this link [reset root password for mysql 8](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-reset-root-password-in-mysql-8-on-ubuntu-linux/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

When you use MySQL's `PASSWORD()` on the system where you want to change the password, it  can cause the password turn up in a MySQL log in cleartext [[source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-logging.html)]. Keeping them, their backups etc. as secure as the password sounds like nightmare to me, so I rather like to do it as follows:

1. On your *local* machine, run this with your password:

   ```
    mysql -u someuser -p < <(echo "SELECT PASSWORD('mypass');")
   ```

   Note the space in front to prevent it from turning up in the bash history (for other distros than Ubuntu, this might work differently – [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32461/18163)).
2. On your server machine, execute the following command to change its MySQL root password (replace `myhash` with your password's hash as printed by the first command):

   ```
   mysql -u root -p < <(echo "SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = 'myhash';")
   ```
3. Optionally, let's be a bit paranoid: On your local machine, clear your terminal screen with `clear` and purge your virtual terminal scrollback, to hide the cleartext password appearing in the command above.

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL don't support the `PASSWORD` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
```

after that please use flush:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 2):

To update the "root" Mysql user password you must have in mind that you will need of super user permissions for that. If you have super user privilegies, try the following commands:

MySQL 5.7.6 and later

```
sudo su
service mysql stop
mysql -u root
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
\q;
exit
mysql -u root -p MyNewPass
```

MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier

```
sudo su
service mysql stop
mysql -u root
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
\q;
exit
mysql -u root -p MyNewPass
```

Answer (score 2):

As mysql documentation on the [password() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) says:

> This function was removed in MySQL 8.0.11.

This invalidates pretty much all existing answers for mysql v8.0.11 and newer.

Per mysql documentation the [new generic way to reset the root password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) is as follows:

> The preceding sections provide password-resetting instructions
>   specifically for Windows and Unix and Unix-like systems.
>   Alternatively, on any platform, you can reset the password using the
>   mysql client (but this approach is less secure):
>
> Stop the MySQL server if necessary, then restart it with the
>   --skip-grant-tables option. This enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges, and disables account-management
>   statements such as ALTER USER and SET PASSWORD. Because this is
>   insecure, if the server is started with the --skip-grant-tables
>   option, it enables --skip-networking automatically to prevent remote
>   connections.
>
> Connect to the MySQL server using the mysql client; no password is
>   necessary because the server was started with --skip-grant-tables:
>
> ```
> shell> mysql
> ```
>
> In the mysql client, tell the server to reload the grant tables so that account-management statements work:
>
> ```
> mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
> ```
>
> Then change the 'root'@'localhost' account password. Replace the password with the password that you want to use.
>   To change the password for a root account with a different host name
>   part, modify the instructions to use that host name.
>
> ```
> mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
> ```
>
> You should now be able to connect to the MySQL server as root using the
>   new password. Stop the server and restart it normally (without the
>   --skip-grant-tables and --skip-networking options).

Comment: These instructions  did not work for me with mysqld version 8.0.19 on Ubuntu 19.10. The mysqld socket is not created when I use the --skip-grant-tables option. If you are in the same situation, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60386378/12559612

Comment: Thanks for your answer, a combination with an old answer works for me:

`sudo service mysql stop
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql: /var/run/mysqld
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`

In another console:

`mysql -uroot mysql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
systemctl restart mysql`

Answer (score 2):

If you know the 'root' users password, log in to mysql with that credentials. Then execute the following query to update the password.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_passowrd';
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of resetting the password there is a work around on the local machine if you have setup `phpmyadmin` to connect without giving the password or username. Check this out by starting `mysql`, `apache` etc. I have `xampp` installed in my local machine. So starting the xampp will start all the necessary services. Now going to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` shows me all the databases. This confirms that you have saved the username and passsword in the config file of phpmyadmin which can be found in the `phpmyadmin` install location. If you have `xampp` installed the `phpmyadmin` folder can be found in the root folder of `xampp` installation. Search for the word `password` in the `config.inc.php` file. There you will find the `password`  and `username`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the mysql password if deployed on xampp through provided phpadmin gui.

```
phpMyAdmin -> User Accounts -> Edit Privileges (Select the intended user) -> Change Password (Tab)
```

Answer (score 1):

for mysql 5.6 this command works and you can set password through the wizard:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.6
```

Comment: I tried but its not working..
I am getting this bellow error.. could you please help?
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.21, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade

Answer (score 1):

I had to go this route on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.  It is somewhat of a mix of some of the other answers above - but none of them helped. I spent an hour or more trying all other suggestions from MySql website to everything on SO, I finally got it working with:

**Note:** while it showed Enter password for user root, I didnt have the original password so I just entered the same password to be used as the new password.

**Note:** there was no /var/log/mysqld.log only /var/log/mysql/error.log

Also note this did not work for me:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7`

Nor did:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force mysql-server-5.5`

Make MySQL service directory.

`sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld`

Give MySQL user permission to write to the service directory.

`sudo chown mysql: /var/run/mysqld`

Then:

1. kill the current mysqld pid
2. run mysqld with sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld &
3. run /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

   **Output from mysql_secure_installation**

   > root@myServer:~# /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
   >
   > Securing the MySQL server deployment.
   >
   > Enter password for user root:
   >
   > VALIDATE PASSWORD PLUGIN can be used to test passwords
   >   and improve security. It checks the strength of password
   >   and allows the users to set only those passwords which are
   >   secure enough. Would you like to setup VALIDATE PASSWORD plugin?
   >
   > Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No: no
   >   Using existing password for root.
   >   Change the password for root ? ((Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >
   > New password:
   >
   > Re-enter new password:
   >   By default, a MySQL installation has an anonymous user,
   >   allowing anyone to log into MySQL without having to have
   >   a user account created for them. This is intended only for
   >   testing, and to make the installation go a bit smoother.
   >   You should remove them before moving into a production
   >   environment.
   >
   > Remove anonymous users? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >   Success.
   >
   > Normally, root should only be allowed to connect from
   >   'localhost'. This ensures that someone cannot guess at
   >   the root password from the network.
   >
   > Disallow root login remotely? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >   Success.
   >
   > By default, MySQL comes with a database named 'test' that
   >   anyone can access. This is also intended only for testing,
   >   and should be removed before moving into a production
   >   environment.
   >
   > Remove test database and access to it? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >
   > - Dropping test database...
   >     Success.
   > - Removing privileges on test database...
   >     Success.
   >
   > Reloading the privilege tables will ensure that all changes
   >   made so far will take effect immediately.
   >
   > Reload privilege tables now? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
   >   Success.
   >
   > All done!

Answer (score 1):

You can try these some steps to reset mysql 5.7 root password :

Stop Mysql Service 1st

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Login as root without password 
`sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` &

After login mysql terminal you should need execute commands more:

```
use mysql;




UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('solutionclub3@*^G'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';


flush privileges;


sudo mysqladmin -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock shutdown
```

After you restart your mysql server
If you still facing error you must visit : 
[Reset MySQL 5.7 root password Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.solutionclub.in/reset-mysql-5-7-root-password-ubuntu-16-04-17-04.html)

Answer (score 1):

Change the MySQL root password. In Simpler way

All these commands should be run as root.

Login through MySQL command line tool using your old password:

***Step-1***

```
mysql -uroot -p"your_old_password"
```

Then run below command:

***Step-2***

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('your_new_password');
```

**Method-2** (First login using your old password using above command)

Run this command, which sets a password for the current user:

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_new_password');
```

Above command is for the current user. If you want to change the password for other user, you can put the user name instead of  **"root"**.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the official steps recommended by the [MySQL 8.0 guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html), which were the only ones that worked for me. Here's a summary of those steps.

1. **Stop the MySQL server if it is running**. Look in `/var/lib/mysql/`, `/var/run/mysqld/`, or `/usr/local/mysql/data/` to find the pid file with the server's process ID. Generally the file begins with either mysqld or your system's host name and ends with .pid.
   Replace `mysql-data-directory` and `host_name` that you just found, in the following command:

   ```
   $ sudo kill `sudo cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid`
   ```
2. This command will **create a text file** in `/tmp/mysql-init` with the SQL statement and makes the mysql user the owner. Replace in the command `MyNewPass` with your own password.

   ```
   $ echo "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';" > /tmp/mysql-init && sudo chown mysql /tmp/mysql-init
   ```
3. **Start the MySQL server** by running the following command on the command line. After this the password is updated and you can close the server again with `CTRL+C`.

   ```
   $ sudo mysqld --user=mysql --init-file=/tmp/mysql-init &
   ```
4. **Remove the temporary file** with your password:

   ```
   $ sudo rm /tmp/mysql-init
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To reset or change the password enter `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-X.X` (X.X is mysql version you have installed i.e. 5.6, 5.7) and then you will prompt a screen where you have to set the new password and then in next step confirm the password and just wait for a moment. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting MySQL Password

1. stop MySQL database service

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

2. create a new mysqld directory

sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld/

3. give mysql user access

sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld/

4. start MySQL in safe mode...

sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

5. logon to the database server without a password

sudo mysql -u root

6. use the default mysql database

use mysql;

7. change the root password

`update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("New_Passwore_Here") where` User='root';

8. Save the changes

   flush privileges;
   exit;
9. stop MySQL safe_mode and start MySQL default service

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

10. log back onto MySQL database using the root new password

sudo mysql -u root -p

*** Source : https://websiteforstudents.com/resetting-mysql-root-password-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-and-18-04-lts/

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL don't support the `PASSWORD` function.

Comment: How is it any different than the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

For those who find password function doesn't work for mysql 8.0 and creating the file and doing the init are very difficult. What I did is drop the root user in the user table in the safe mode as many mentioned above. And create the root user again by referring to
https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04/784347#784347, Then do

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password(this is the plugin which specified in the user table) BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Hope someone can find this when above doesn't work. Try this way.

Answer (score -1):

when changing/resetting the MySQL password the following commands listed above did not help. I found that going into the terminal and using these commands is pointless. instead use the command sudo stop everything. DELETE SYSTEM 32 for windows if that helps.

Comment: The question is about `ubuntu` OS not windows. What do you mean by _DELETE SYSTEM 32 for windows_?