# MySql change mysql password [ERROR] Can't find messagefile

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I wanted to change mysql password ([How to reset or change the MySQL root password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password))

**logs:**

```
root@vm87297:[/usr/share/mysql]: 
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
* Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                 [ OK ] 

root@vm87297:[/usr/share/mysql]: 
$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 6503

root@vm87297:[/usr/share/mysql]: 
$ 140820  6:11:20 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysqlmyisam-recover-options = BACKUP/errmsg.sys'
^C
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

**mysql version:**

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

**ubuntu:**

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Thanks!

Comment: I think the mysql configuration is wrong since the error msg is never been seen if my.cnf has some improper configuration of variables.

Try the following command and check the error log :

`mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql --lc-messages-dir="/usr/local/mysql/share/english/"`

Still the problem persists, Plz share the my.cnf to sweep out the issue.