# Failed to connect to mysql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password:YES)

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I've been trying to create a new database connection on workbench. However, every time I test a connection there is an error message that says

> Failed to connect to mysql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password:YES)

I don't know what's the cause of this error. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing my workbench 6.1 and mysql server 5.6 but the error is still unsolved.

Comment: What's tenlet? @ydoow

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password/51444744#51444744

Answer (score 47):

First check if it's a workbench or connection problem.

1) In your windows run 'cmd' to open a terminal

Try both

2a) `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306`

2b) `mysql -u root -p -h > localhost -P 3306`

3) If the connection is good you will get a password prompt, see if you can connect with correct password.

If your connection is denied, just grant the permission

```
mysql >GRANT ALL ON [DatabaseName].* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]';
```

If your connection is accepted here, it's like a workbench configuration problem.

Comment: I don't have any database connection yet. Even if I try using localhost as my hostname it still doesn't work. @ydoow

Comment: 'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. -- this message appears after entering mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306. @ydoow

Comment: Run the command in MySQL bin directory. Typically the directory is something like C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server x.x

Comment: what is the "database name"?, i just installed it.

Comment: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
Enter password: (hiding pw)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Followed your steps and it's denying me access.

Comment: @UnAlpha then it's a permission issue.

Comment: Permission issue as in run as administrator?  Please provide more detail what you mean by this.

Comment: I'm getting this after entering password: `ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '-P' (11001)`

Comment: How will you grant access if the login isn't working?

Comment: @AllenKing this is to rule out connection or permission issue. You would still need to make sure the service is running and credential is correct.

Comment: Its giving syntax error in mysql 8

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem. 
I've installed fresh mysql at Ubuntu but I left mysql password empty, and as a result I couldn't connect to mysql in any way.
 
Lately I've revealed that there is a table of users where are names, hosts, passwords and some plugins. So for my user root@localhost mysql while installing assigned a plugin called **auth_socket**, which let Unix user "root" log in as a mysql user "root" without password, but don't allow login as another Unix user. So to fix that you should turn off this plugin and set usual authentication:

1. open Linux terminal
2. enter "**sudo mysql**"
   you will see "mysql >" which means you've connected to mysql as a 'root' Unix user and you can type SQL queries.
3. enter SQL query to change a way how you will log in:
   **ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_new_password';**
   where 'mysql_native_password' means - to turn off auth_socket plugin.

Comment: A good way to check if this is causing the issue is to just run `sudo mysql`, if it let's you in that means that the *auth_socket* plugin is enabled and probably causing the issue. Great answer by the way, thanks.

Comment: When using `sudo mysql`, I'm facing this: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found. Library path is 'caching_sha2_password.dll'`

Answer (score 19):

Try this, it worked for me!

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Inside the terminal enter:

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Then in the MySQL Workbench edit the connection and change the root name to admin.

Comment: where does this get entered? is there a terminal within workbench?

Comment: ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT

Comment: when using `sudo mysql -u root -p` in terminal, nothing happens. Is that right? no output, no errors..

Comment: For mysql is running on docker . I tried this steps but it does not work . Please suggest any solution .

Comment: After spending hours... and HOURS... literally trying everything to get workbench to work with root, nothing worked so I tried this and boom, I cancan get in with Workbench using the new admin user, took about 30 seconds

Answer (score 18):

I was facing the same problem in windows.

1. Goto services in task manager
2. start the service called MySQL80
3. Restart workbench

Comment: What if it's already running?

Answer (score 14):

> In Ubuntu systems running MySQL 5.7 (and later versions), the root MySQL user is set to authenticate using the **auth_socket plugin** by default rather than with a password. This allows for some greater security and usability in many cases, **but it can also complicate things when you need to allow an external program (e.g., phpMyAdmin) to access the user.**
>
> If you prefer to use a password when connecting to MySQL as **root**, you will need to switch its authentication method from **auth_socket** to **mysql_native_password**.
> [source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04)

Open up the MySQL prompt from your terminal:

```
$ sudo mysql
```

Next, check which authentication method each of your MySQL user accounts use with the following command:

```
mysql > SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

You will see that the root user does in fact authenticate using the auth_socket plugin. To configure the root account to authenticate with a password, run the following `ALTER USER` command. Be sure to change password to a strong password of your choosing:

```
mysql > ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Then, run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` which tells the server to reload the grant tables and put your new changes into effect:

```
mysql > FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Check the authentication methods employed by each of your users again to confirm that root no longer authenticates using the **auth_socket plugin**:

```
mysql > SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

You will see in output that the root MySQL user now authenticates using a password.

Comment: I may be thick, but I looked all over to solve this problem and the first part of the solution was simply to execute #mysql as root (or sudo should  have worked).  Then I could add a user other than root (on ubuntu, I don't know the root password).

Comment: This was *exactly* the issue, with a simple to follow set of steps to solve the problem. Kudos!!!

Answer (score 6):

You should install the mysql server which hosts in your localhost. Then install the workbench. Still if you are getting the error GOTO:

(In MAC:)

System preferences>Mysql(Will be listed at the bottom,else server is not installed in your machine).

Check server status and start the Mysql server.

Try connecting to localhost with default port number.

Comment: Fixed my problem. I tried to connect, but MySQL wasn't started lol

Comment: [macOS] This is the right answer in 2024. For some reason MySQL server will not be launched after installing.

Answer (score 6):

i just encountered this problem now and with some tries i figured out that **visiting services >> select MySQLxx service , then right click and hit start** , that solved my problem and everything is working without the need to loss data.

Answer (score 5):

Just go back to your installer and add SQL servers, if its already there just reconfigure it and add password from there,

Go back to your workbench and delete the current users and create a new one with the same password you used during server configuration

Comment: This should be the first thing to check on Windows! Solved my issue, thank you!

Comment: Thanks I had the same issue and this worked like a charm!

Comment: This might be useful knowing how to navigate the wizard when reconfiguring the server: https://ladvien.com/data-analytics-mysql-localhost-setup/ (I have no affiliation with that link, just found it)

Comment: Thank you for your reminder! For me, I silly installed only the MySQL Workbench (instead of MySQL Installer Community) so I didn't have server to start.

Answer (score 4):

After viewing so many solution answers, here is my summary which works for me.
I only installed workbench 6.2 at first, when connecting to localhost it failed.

step1: check if you have installed mysql server. If not, download and install.

step2: the mysql server configuration recommend strong password, ignore it, choose the legacy password.

step3: start mysql server (windows system: services-->mysql-->start)

step4: open workbench and create local connection.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL Installer Community -> MySQL Server Reconfigure -> Next -> Next -> Connection Name [Local instance or any other name] -> Click on Password - Store in Vault... and add a password and then -> Test connection.
It works for me :)

Answer (score 3):

no idea how this happened, but i had the same problem.  I had to reset my root password:
http://www.jovicailic.org/2012/04/reset-forgotten-mysql-root-password-under-windows/

But after my databases that i had previously were either dropped or the new connection did not connect to them.  Either way i couldn't access them via workbench.  But i could use MySQL again, which was a win for me

Comment: I have since found that this error was related to a windows update.  I don't know why, but whenever windows (7) auto updated on my server i would have the same error.  I check with my IT department, but they couldn't figure it out either.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

I hope this will help You

1. Uninstalled everything including installer from it's own uninstall option.
2. Un-installed all the programs that were in any way related to mysql
3. Deleted the mysql folder from C:\Program Files
4. Deleted the mysql folder from C:\ProgramData
5. Cleared my registry and then re-installed the program, but all in vain.

How to repeat:
Here is what I did:

1. Installed it with mysql-installer-web-community-5.6.23.0.msi
2. For my purposes I selected "Custom" install with MySQL servers 5.6.22 - X64 and MySQL Connectors -> Connector ODBC/5.3.4 - 64
3. Next -> Execute -(ready to configure) -> Next
4. Config type: Development machine, all defaults (TCP/IP, Port: 3306, Open firewall)
5. Typed in MySQL Root Password
6. MySQL user Accounts -> Add user (username, password, OK) -> Next
7. Configure MySQL Server as a Windows Service (CHECKED)
8. Windows Service Name: MySQL56 (default)
9. Start the MySQL Serve at System Startup
10. THIS IS CRUCIAL (BUG IS HERE): Run Service as... Standard System Account (CHECKED - but it will be disregarded and that is BUG)
11. Next -> Execute, Installation hangs on Starting server, so wait for a while to time out (or don't, your choice). When Dialog (might be covered with other windows) popup with message "Configuration of MySQL Server is taking longer than expected..., here click OK (so to wait longer)

Suggested fix:
12. Meanwhile go to Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services -> find MySQL56, right click on it -> Properties -> select Log On Tab AND HERE IS BUG -> Although Local System Account was selected, Somehow "This account: Network Service (with some password) was selected -> Select Log on as: Local System Account, Allow service to interact with desktop -> Apply -> Go back on general tab

13. On general tab click on "Start" button to start service and here it is! Service is started! Click on OK to close MySQL56 Properties dialog. Close Services dialog. Close Administrative tools. Close control panel.
14. And by that time (while you were closing those dialogs) when you look at MySQl Installer Dialog all steps are finished and checked: Starting Server, Applying security... Creating user accounts.. Updating Start menu link
15. Confirm with Finish -> Next -> Finish
    That's it, happy MySQL-ing :)

Source: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76476

Answer (score 2):

Go to the search bar on your Windows and search for **Services**.
Launch **Services** and look for **MySQL*xx*** (*xx* depends on your MySQL version) in the long list of services. **Right-click** on MySQLxx and hit **Start**. 
MySQL should work fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, but it worked for me.

1. check if you have mysql installed

   [image]

If you don't have mysql installed, download from this link: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

2. follow this instructions to install
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-osx-excerpt/5.7/en/osx-installation-pkg.html
3. You can test the connection without any problem.

(Sorry for my english, I agree fix me please)

I Hope I've helped.
Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

i think the problem is we are trying to connect to a local server
that is not running.

we need to first run the `MySQL` server then connect to it.

just Go to task manager > services
find `MYSQL80` and then start the service.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. sudo mysql -u root -p
2. mysql > ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'abc@123';
3. sudo mysql-workbench

Answer (score 1):

Don`t worry about it. just open MySql Installer Community from start menu or your program file and reconfig "**Mysql Server**" and "**Samples and Example**"
focus on  Samples and Example config... and tik mark on Mysql Server, enter your password, click on check and finally click on next and finish.
Hope you will see the success message.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with **MySQL version 8.0.23.**

I solved it in the following way:

**1**. Opening again the **msi installer** for windows.

**2**. In **MySQL Server** I clicked on "**Reconfigure**".

**3**. Then I clicked on the following steps until I got to "**Accounts and
Roles**" and there **I **set the password**** for "**root**".

**4**. Finally in **SQL Workbench**, I went to **Manage Server Connections** and
clicked on "**store in Vault...**" where I entered the **same password** as
in **step 3**.

*PS*: This procedure also creates the **MySQL Service on window**s which also helps to solve **this problem**.

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue when trying to create a mySQL connection on workbench.
Problem with me was I downloaded incompatible mySQL .dmg file from [mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). Re-installing 'macOS 11 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive' instead of 'macOS 11 (ARM, 64-bit), DMG Archive' solved my issue.
I suggest you to try re-installing the compatible dmg file for your OS

Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very edge case, but you cannot use passwords with an apostrophe ('). The password I created while setting up MySQL Server had an apostrophe (') in it, and it was always giving me the error you mentioned.

As soon as I changed to a password without the apostrophe, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have read all the above solutions and none of them worked in my case, So the main error was "MySQL server was not running or installed, Workbench could not find any server" I installed **XAMPP server** and started MySQL server. The connection then established on Workbench
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are a mac user try this method

Go to System Preferences > MYSQL > Initialize Database > Enter password

Hope this helps

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I have come across this issue as well but found a fix for this that worked for me:

1. go to "Services"
2. under "Name" find your username
3. right click and select "Start"

Go to your MySQL workbench and select "Startup / Shutdown" under "INSTANCE" and you should be good to go. Hope this helps anyone that comes across this.

Answer (score 0):

i changed default password from " " with space to blank

Comment: Is the question really around this?

Answer (score 0):

this could happen due to version issues . I had the same issue and I downgraded my mySQL work bench and tried it. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Did not have MySQL server installed, only MySQL workbench.

I had the same issue after trying to set up a GitHub project on a new computer. I noticed that Visual Studio 2019 gave an error that my program could not connect to the MySQL server, so I opened my MySQL Workbench and there I could also not connect.

It took me a lot longer than I'd like to admit to notice that my new device did not have MySQL server installed. You can download it on [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). For some reason it first updated my MySQL workbench before I could install MySQL server (maybe I read to fast).

Make sure that you click on **add** on [this screen](https://www.screencast.com/t/iSLjlvxiW) if you don't have MySQL server installed yet.

Answer (score 0):

On mac the answers above unfortunately didn't work causing a `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Doing the following worked for me:

```
sudo su
mysql -uroot
set password = password("password");
```

Took me embarassingly long to figure out hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Access the database as a user administrator (root user maybe). Check the right one user privileges to the database.

```
mysql >SHOW GRANTS FOR <username>;
```

Assign full user privileges to the database from localhost

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <databasename>.* TO '<username>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

in case of error in connecting to the database from third-party programs, for example MySQL WORKBENCH, assign privileges to the user to the database from any host 
MYSQL Grant all privileges to database from any host

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <databasename>.* TO '<username>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out if you are install MySQL server, I've faced this issue and resolve it by this steps:

1- Windows > MySQL installer - community
2- Then click on Add > then select MySQL Server and next.
.....

I hope that resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

For Mac,

I fixed it by re-entering root password.

`System Preferences > MYSQL > Initialize Database > Enter password`

[image: Initialize Database]

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue after using Vast cleanup. Basically mysql instance starts on PC startup and it is active in background all the time even when not in use.

Mistakenly I've stopped it

> Failed to connect to mysql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password:YES)

Solution which worked for me:

type in mysql command line client. As soon as you open you will be prompted with password

-> mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306

and finally it works even when you switch back to workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me on `Windows10`:

1. Go to `Services` and find the MYSQL service, than `STOP` it.
2. Open `Notepad` and enter the following line:

> ```
> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
> ```

than save the file to the root of your hard drive (C:\ ). Choose a filename that makes sense, such as mysql-init.txt.

3. Navigate to the MySQL directory using the command prompt (run as administrator):

> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"

4. Enter the following:

> mysqld --init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt

5. Now, you can log into your MySQL server as root using the new password and you can delete the C:\mysql-init.txt file.
6. Go to `Services` and `START` your MYSQL service.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Mysql server is started.
It can be run by :  CMD => "MySQL Installer"

See video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlefNPcb_Qg&ab_channel=NateBoorsma

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same problem and finally, I got the solution...

1. Open MySQL Installer.
2. After that you see the Reconfigure option in the front of the MySQL Server. Click on it.
3. After that you have to click on the Next buttons without changing any default settings.

Comment: Provide more insight with the answer of why this will fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was also faced with this problem. But I handle this solution.

1. Just click right to MySQL Workbench app>>
2. then open file location. And here you can find Installer for Window >>
3. open and start the installer. This is the install configuration.

Open it and then choose your MySQL Server and reconfig.

After it, you should fill authen.

1. Use legacy Auth.. >>
2. Roles>>
3. set pass. >> then don't change anything.. go and execute it. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was to open MySQL installer community then under quick actions press reconfigure the settings then it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, but the underlying issue was sort of differen...
I tried to connect to localhost inside MySQL Workbench, but it did not even find a connected SQL Server instance,
the problem was, that the mysql service was not installed under windows. So I opened cmd as administrator and typed `mysqld --install`, restarted the workbench and mySQL was properly detected, I could connect and execute all other mysql related commands...

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHYaI.png - click on "ADD"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzSOD.png - select a server from the given list

next ->  next ->  add a password and click "finish"..

- check the connection using the workbench

Answer (score 0):

In sone case, not working with Workbench but is worked with Datagrip.

Answer (score 0):

First check if MySQL Server is installed on your system or just MySQL workbench.

If MySQL server is not installed first install it and then you can go to Settings -> environment variables -> path and add the MySQL path from program files where MySQL has been installed.

This must resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

***EASY WAY***

When you've been asked to enter the password after clicking Test Connection, you need to enter your root password. This means you have to enter the password of your main user (the password you use to log into the operating system). This will grant you access to the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I was to facing the same database connections issue in MySQL workbench.

Install MySQL workbench latest i am using MySQL Workbench 8.0 setup all the things as default.

Install MySQL Community Server `MySQL Community Server 8.2.0 Innovation` given then link [enter link description here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

setup all of the things as default.

set the password as per your wish

than connect the database and it's done

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who have install mysql using homebrew you should be able to redefine password for your root user using the following command.

Make sure your mysql server is running

```
mysql.server status
```

Now, run this command you should be able to set the password and set other configurations and then continue on....

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

Answer (score -1):

Well i had this problem, during an installation on Mac os, i tried multiple times to remove mysql 8.O and reinstall, for my vintage mac the only solution that i found was to take the CAKEBREW services and download a 5.7 mysql + an old Mysql Workbench 5. also, all is working perfectly, i will wait until somebody fix this problem.

I hope you found an other solution .

Answer (score -3):

Here was my solution:

- press Ctrl + Alt + Del
- Task Manager
- Select the Services Tab
- Under name, right click on "MySql" and select Start