# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP). I am finding problems while wiring my database using CakePHP.

Below is my application configuration.

I am on Bitnami WAMP stack 5.4.40-0.
I am using CakePHP 3.0.4 to create a web MVC application

Entry for datasources in my `app.php` file.

```
/**
 * Connection information used by the ORM to connect
 * to your application's datastores.
 * Drivers include Mysql Postgres Sqlite Sqlserver
 * See vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Driver for complete list
 */
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        /**
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        //'port' => 'nonstandard_port_number',
        'username' => 'test2',
        'password' => 'computer',
        'database' => 'jobs',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,

        /**
         * Set identifier quoting to true if you are using reserved words or
         * special characters in your table or column names. Enabling this
         * setting will result in queries built using the Query Builder having
         * identifiers quoted when creating SQL. It should be noted that this
         * decreases performance because each query needs to be traversed and
         * manipulated before being executed.
         */
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

        /**
         * During development, if using MySQL < 5.6, uncommenting the
         * following line could boost the speed at which schema metadata is
         * fetched from the database. It can also be set directly with the
         * mysql configuration directive 'innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'
         * which is the recommended value in production environments
         */
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
    ],
```

I have already created a database table called *jobs* according to CakePHP conventions. User test2 has global privileges the same as the root administrator.

But when I am running the bake all command, I am getting the following error:

```
2015-07-01 06:24:56 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test2'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Stack Trace:
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.40-0\apache2\htdocs\myjobs\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Driver\PDODriverTrait.php(48): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'test2', 'computer', Array)
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.40-0\apache2\htdocs\myjobs\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Driver\Mysql.php(89): Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql->_connect('mysql:host=127....', Array)
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.40-0\apache2\htdocs\myjobs\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Schema\BaseSchema.php(46): Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql->connect()
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED (UPDATE)**

I followed Ankit and Spencer's directions.

I had a couple of problems.

1. Host of my user was not localhost; it was a wildcard `%`. Changed that, then MySQL started refusing connections.
2. I disabled my firewall and found that the port was different from 3306. So I changed the entry in `app.php`. Now my application is baked :)

Comment: `Access denied for user 'test2'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` that's pretty unambiguous. _Does_ the user test2 have access? I.e. does this work: `mysql -utest2 -pcomputer jobs` ?

Comment: strange, changing `%` to `localhost` really worked for me... Also it might create another user - delete the one with the `%` host

Comment: Restarting MySQL after those changes is the icing on the cake.

Comment: this same error occurs when you have missed the extension of the php file. In my case app.php  was app with no extension, after adding the extension, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to connect to mysql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password:YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777943/failed-to-connect-to-mysql-at-127-0-0-13306-with-user-root-access-denied-for-us)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That error message usually means that either the password we are using doesn't match what MySQL thinks the password should be for the user we're connecting as, or a matching MySQL user doesn't exist (hasn't been created).

In MySQL, a user is identified by both a username ("test2") **and** a host ("localhost").

The error message identifies the *user* ("test2") and the *host* ("localhost") values...

```
  'test2'@'localhost'
```

We can check to see if the user exists, using this query from a client we can connect from:

```
 SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user
```

We're looking for a row that has "test2" for *user*, and "localhost" for *host*.

```
 user     host       
 -------  -----------
 test2     127.0.0.1  cleanup
 test2     ::1        
 test2     localhost
```

If that row doesn't exist, then the host may be set to wildcard value of `%`, to match any other host that isn't a match.

If the row exists, then the password may not match. We can change the password (if we're connected as a user with sufficient privileges, e.g. `root`

```
 SET PASSWORD FOR 'test2'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mysecretcleartextpassword')
```

We can also verify that the user has privileges on objects in the database.

```
 GRANT SELECT ON jobs.* TO 'test2'@'localhost'
```

---

**EDIT**

If we make changes to mysql privilege tables with DML operations (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE), those changes will not take effect until MySQL re-reads the tables. We can make changes effective by forcing a re-read with a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` statement, executed by a privileged user.

Comment: thanks a ton Spencer...indeed my user's host was a wildcard value, changed that...and also the port was different than 3306..now my baking of database is sucessfull :)

Comment: Don't forget FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: @EricKorolev  yes, the FLUSH PRIVILEGES statement is needed after DML (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE) changes to the mysql tables, to make those changes take effect. It's not required after a SET PASSWORD or GRANT statement (as shown in my answer), since those changes are automatically made effective without a FLUSH PRIVILEGES.

Answer (score 8):

Check Following Things

- Make Sure You Have MySQL Server Running
- Check connection with default credentials i.e. username : 'root' & password : '' [Blank Password]
- Try login phpmyadmin with same credentials
- Try to put 127.0.0.1 instead localhost or your lan IP would do too.
- Make sure you are running MySql on 3306 and if you have configured make sure to state it while making a connection

Comment: I change 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' and fix problem.

Answer (score 6):

I saw it's solved, but I still want to share a solution which worked for me.

.env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=[your database name]
DB_USERNAME=[your MySQL username]
DB_PASSWORD=[your MySQL password]
```

MySQL admin:

```
 SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user
```

[Thank you, spencer7593](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8DUB.png)

Console:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Now it works for me.

[Laracasts answers](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/6#comment-3433817215)

Answer (score 2):

If you use MAMP, you might have to set the socket:
unix_socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Answer (score 2):

If all database details are correct please use database password as a string in .env file.

```
DB_PASSWORD='your_password'
```

Comment: @borma425 Your'e welcome this is the easiest way to address this issue  :)

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to the answers posted on above that none of the solutions proposed here worked for me. My WAMP, is working on port 3308 instead of 3306 which is what it is installed by default.
I found out that when working in a local environment, if you are using mysqladmin in your computer (for testing environment), and if you are working with port other than 3306, you must define your variable DB_SERVER with the value localhost:NumberOfThePort, so it will look like the following: 
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost:3308"). You can obtain this value by right-clicking on the WAMP icon in your taskbar (on the hidden icons section) and select Tools. You will see the section: "Port used by MySQL: NumberOfThePort"

This will fix your connection to your database.

This was the error I got:
Error: SQLSTATE[HY1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' on line X.

I hope this helps you out.

:)