# Laravel 5.3 in LAMP - migration not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using `laravel 5.3`.

Recently I have setup my project on `Ubuntu 14.04` and moved my project to `LAMP`, before this it was on `WAMP`.

My `.env` file is as:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=somebase64key
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE="local.d2d.com"
DB_USERNAME=d2d
DB_PASSWORD=
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

Yes, I have user `d2d` and have all privileges on database `local.d2d.com` in `mysql`.

My `config/database.php` is as:

```
<?php

return [
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'default' => 'mysql',
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ]
    ],

    'migrations' => 'migrations',
    'redis' => [
        'cluster' => false,
        'default' => [
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ]
    ]
];
```

While running `php artisan migrate`, I am getting following error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select *
>   from information_schema.tables where table_schema = local.d2d.com and
>   table_name = migrations)
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>                                                                                  [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

You can see I am **NOT USING** `root` user anywhere still I am facing this issue. Even in the connection error you may find the database is `information_schema` instead of `local.d2d.com`.

Yes, I have ran `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan view:clear`, `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize` many times.

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you restarted your laravel server? If else stop the current server, start it again and run the config and cache clear commands and let me know.

Comment: @ArunCode I have run ```sudo service apache2 restart``` and cleared config as well as cache, still the same problem is there.

Comment: @R.Mazarei I had also tried it but it seems not working.

Comment: also clear your config cache.

Comment: I didn't notice the error message so I deleted my comment, it wasn't what I thought.

Comment: If you are using laravel-doctrine as ORM make sure you add the ServiceProvider to the providers array and publish the config by running `php artisan vendor:publish --tag="config"`. I'm not sure but I think you must have a password setup.

Comment: @Jimi check if you find a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31154458/3918473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `config/database.php` like this:

```
<?php
    ...
    'mysql' => [
        ...
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'example'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        ...
    ],
    ...
```

then

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```