# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to take all information from my database. Bu when i refresh the page error access denied occurs. How can i solve this. Can you please help me?

this is database.php;

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

this is .env;

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:HMSysJsvQBx9lKnctKT2Z+7Gv//of2W8O18uD+5wO0o=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

 LOG_CHANNEL=stack

 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=blog
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=
```

The error is: 
**"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `tasks`)"**

Comment: you can follow [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154124/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernamelocalhost-using-cakep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154124/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernamelocalhost-using-cakep)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1045\] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' using CakePhp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154124/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernamelocalhost-using-cakep)

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Or

```
php artisan config:cache
```

You will receive:

Configuration cache cleared!

Configuration cached successfully!

You must remember that .env datas are keep in laravel cache engine. So clear cache everytime when you make any changes in `.env`

Comment: I did them bu it is not solution sir.

Comment: User name Host name Type Privileges Grant Action
 root 127.0.0.1 global ALL PRIVILEGES Yes Edit privileges Edit privileges Export Export
 root ::1 global ALL PRIVILEGES Yes Edit privileges Edit privileges Export Export
 root localhost global ALL PRIVILEGES Yes Edit privileges Edit privileges Export Export

Comment: I have 3 users is this normal?

Comment: it depends on your configuration. did u try to connect with database without laravel, just for test?

Comment: Yes i connected. Even i migrated. i manually created tasks table but  i didn't create a task model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to clear your config cache. Restart your application or run `php artisan config:cache` from your command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Check on different browser better to check on chrome incognito after these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your username and password in the .env file are correct. It might be that user doesn't exist, or that the user has a password