# Laravel 5.6 cannot connect to database after clearing cache

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5, config

i cannot connect to database after clearing even php artisan is not working.
here is how i clear config caches:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

then it's cleared successfully but when i run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

i got this error:

```
<pre><strong>ERROR:</strong> Can't connect to the database server. SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)</pre>%
```

i also tried: `composer dump-autoload`
but still no luck. Once in the past i got same error and i was able to solve it but no idea how. If someone knows solution then kindly explain it as well.

My php version: `PHP 7.2.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May  5 2018 05:00:15) ( NTS )`

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154124/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernamelocalhost-using-cakep

Comment: can use dump-autoload -o along with it need to give the permission to the user and check your hostname

Comment: @AnandMishra that even doesn't work and i have posted answer of it when i find out it's solution.

Answer (score 0):

User you are using to connect the database in not having privilege to connect, please provide that access to your db user

Comment: **''** **(empty)** is not user ? also it's always using **localhost** as **hostname** even if i try to change it or not in **.env** file. But after spending few minutes i've find solution am i allowed to answer my own question?

Comment: @AmmadKhalid  you can comment the solution and use .env file  to keep db credential.

Comment: yes i always .env and i just post that solution as answer. But we are allowed to answer to own questions? if no one able to find answer before you?

Comment: The issue is not with cache is issue is with the db user that you are using, please check you credential.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/RF1fRUw.png 
you can see i used **root** but it was showing **''** which means empty because maybe it don't cache the user.

Comment: There is must be something wrong with my app. Otherwise it should cache completely.

Comment: this detail should be share earlier for better understanding,
try using
composer update -o

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i'm allowed to answer my own question or not. Let me know if it's not allowed to answer to your question.

In **bootstrap** directory which is located in **root** of your app. There i saw **cache** directory and then i just delete it and run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

then it's works. But even if i try to run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

it gonna be successful. But if after this you may get same error again:

```
php artisan serve
```

```
ERROR: Can't connect to the database server. SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

After this i try to delete **config.php** inside **bootstrap/cache/**.
it gonna work even after deleting that file.

Comment: But still `php artisan config:cache` will not work and that is maybe there is something wrong with my app.