# trouble connecting to mysql with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to connect to MySQL database with pdo but keep getting this error:

Warning: Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\first\index.php on line 2

Warning: Use of undefined constant password - assumed 'password' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\first\index.php on line 2

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\first\index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\first\index.php(2): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'username', 'password') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\first\index.php on line 2

here's my code:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=dbname', username, password);
 ?>
```

Comment: you did not define the constants username and password, or you meant to type $username and $password. (or you forgot the quotes: "username" when that actually your username to be used...)

Comment: and always start reading the first error or warning message. Once that is solved 9 out of 10 times the other errors are gone as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154124/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernamelocalhost-using-cakep seems to have good answer

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154124/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-usernamelocalhost-using-cakep

Answer (score 0):

It's because the username and password are not variables.  They are missing the $

```html
<?php

$username = 'myUsername';
$password = 'myPassword';

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=dbname', $username, $password);
 ?>
```

Comment: I tries: <?php

$username = 'myUsername';
$password = 'myPassword';

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=dbname', $username, $password);
 ?> now I get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myUsername'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\first\index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\first\index.php(8): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'myUsername', 'myPassword') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\first\index.php on line 8

Comment: yes, that is because you did not replace `myUsername` with the username that you are using.  You need to replace `myUsername` and `myPassword` with the correct credentials

Comment: I don't know what you mean by correct credentials, is this my computer username and password?

Comment: you need to add the credentials that you created for the user you created for the mysql database you're trying to access.