# Configuration of MYSQL connectivity in django framework

Tags: mysql, django

Well, I'm trying to connect MYSQL database to Django , I have installed mysql installer 8.0 version, after installation in the Accounts and Roles section its not taking root account password and also I m not getting to change the password option, please help if anyone faced the same problem , let me know if any solution for this . How do I change the MYSQL root account password

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL workbench for GUI and you just have to create a new database in it after that, find the settings in your project's settings.py file and change to this,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'YOUR_DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'YOUR_USERNAME',
        'PASSWORD': 'YOUR_DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306
    }
}
```

and run this :

> pip install mysqlclient

Comment: yeah, I have tried with MYSQL workbench also but while creating new database , I m getting the below error, please suggest how to fix this error:

Comment: Error:  Cant connect to 127.0.0.1:3036  with user ,

Comment: @Amrapali Kumari 
try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777943/failed-to-connect-to-mysql-at-127-0-0-13306-with-user-root-access-denied-for-us