# What should I use instead of 'password' in a future release

Tags: mysql

When issuing the statement:

```
mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('11111') where user='root';
```

I get the response:

> Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec) Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1
>
> Warning (Code 1681): 'PASSWORD' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

What should I use instead of 'password' in a future release?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208000/update-user-password-in-mysql-5-7

Comment: ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';

Comment: The `PASSWORD()` function was never intended to be used in application tables, it was just for hashing passwords for database users.

Comment: Are you using PHP to process the password setting? There are lots of questions here showing how to use PHP functions to hash the password. I can't find any good answers that are just MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

They're going to remove the `PASSWORD` command and add a new command for changing passwords that is `SET CREDENTIALS`.

It works like this:

```
SET CREDENTIALS FOR 'root' TO '11111';
```

They're changing it because they didn't like the idea of using the regular `UPDATE` command for changing the database password since its a thing for updating database values, not database config. If you're curious then you can read about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=6409).

Comment: He's not setting user credentials for the database, he's updating an application table.