# MySQL 1064 (42000) Syntax Error - while copy/pasting recommended code (update user) from websites (here too!)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is an edit to comply with stackoverflow rules.

My original question for a small private offline diary was solved BY RITWIK MATH'S SUGGESTION BELOW.

My curiousity is still why I could not copy-paste mySQL syntax from all kinds of websites, including here, without getting syntax errors.

**I'm going to close this myself tonight - I'm just still curious. Thanks!**

**Basically, I can't use help websites or how tos on this because I'm getting Syntax errors on copy-and-paste:**

[...]

**But I have no access to the "root" password and can't change it, because whatever I copy-paste from all websites, I'm getting 1064/42000 Syntax errors around the NEWPASSWORD and ROOT terms.**

[...]

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-change-and-recover-a-mysql-root-password/

```
mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('NEWPASSWORD') where user='root';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('NEWPASSWORD') where user='root'' at line 1
```

I've tried all variations I can imagine (I tried backticks, too, not knowing if what looked like 'user' was `user`).
I think a syntax error is unlikely if code is found in so many places, so what's wrong??

[...]

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Have you tried it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32430050/1213708) answer

Comment: Yes, I've tried this one two - not the deprecated versions, but the "update user..." and, when this threw a syntax error, the "alter user". in both cases I used 'copy and paste' using right-click mouse button.

Comment: Please share more details. Which version of MySQL are you using? You have only provided a single attempt to set the password

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know which version I'm using since I installed it as a package. As Ritwik Math (below) sais correctly, I don't know the basics. Therefore I searched for websites with solutions to similar questions, took their suggestions how to set or update or alter the root password, and always got the same syntax error. I'm sorry I can't provide more detail. But thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can always go for XAMPP... I personally host my wordpress website locally using XAMPP... Another great alternative is Local by flywheel... this the link ... https://localwp.com/
Stop copy pasting without understanding at least the basics...

Comment: localwp.com is the ideal solution for me, thank you so much! It did not show up in all my searching (neither text based nor YouTube) because I always searched for "install Wordpress locally". Only when using "Wordpress locally" as search term it was there. It is very hard to find if one does not know it exists, I think. But it's exactly what I need!

Comment: However, if anybody would like to answer, I would still be curious to know why copy-pasting the above code did not work. Do I get you right, Ritwik Math, that this syntax error has nothing to do with the syntax itself (so, it would generally work in mySQL)? That it is only interpreted as a 'syntax error' because I messed something up elsewhere? Only curious. Thanks.

Comment: Can't vote you up because I'm too new, sorry.

Comment: Please share more details. Why should using any other software than a pure MySQL server resolve the given problem?

Comment: My original intention to run/use Wordpress locally (just for a small private project) is solved ideally by using 'Local'. This does not solve my copy-pasting issue, but I changed my initial question in an attempt to comply with forum rules, so this might be confusing. My apologies. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @NicoHaase Would you consider upvoting Ritwik Math again, please? I edited my message AFTER he answered, so I changed the initial question and it is my fault it now seems as if he was not replying to the problem! He solved my main question.