# Laravel forge database issue

Tags: php, laravel, forge

I have a problem connecting to the Laravel Forge database. I've imported a project from my GitHub repository, and provided Forge with GitHub token. I can SSH into server, but if I try to run migrations I get error:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Which is somehow expected since I didn't get database password. For servers before I used to got a mail with all the necessary data, but not on this one. And now I don't know what credentials to use?

Is there a workaround or something to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Since mysql user passwords aren't kept in plain text, you have three  options:

1. Find the email ;)
2. Create new user with forge - MySQL tab
3. SSH and reset your MySQL password - [How to reset or change the MySQL root password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password)

Answer (score 0):

I've had Forge not send me login information after creating servers as well. I ended up just destroying the box and recreating it.