# mysql won't accept my password when using it as a regular user

Tags: mysql, capistrano

When I try to deploy my app I get this error

Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

when I try to log in to sql as root it works

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
```

but when I try to log in as a normal user I get the error

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Why mysql root password works for system root but doesn't work for the systems regular user?

## solution

answer to this question has helped to some extent

https://serverfault.com/questions/254629/unable-to-install-mysql-server-in-ubuntu

also I had to remove offending file from apparmor

Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 9: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'

So I had to run this command to get rid of the error. 
After that Mysql got instaled cleanly and I can log in as regular user.

rm /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

Comment: **Solution:** Reset root password: [Post by Christian Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16556534/6214696)

Comment: nothing I tried worked, when I tried to purge mysql following this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/640899/uninstall-mysql-completely it seemed I was able to set new password when installing mysql from scratch, but nuo I'm stuck at apparmor problems  AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 9: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: Are you using MariaDB?

Comment: @Solitaire - no, it's mysql

Comment: Check `select plugin from user where User='root';` Can you login as non-root-mysql-user from non-root?

Comment: do self-answers below, don't put the solution you found in your question block. All that reads as is confusion and it wastes people's time wondering, wait, did he fix it, huh

Comment: I consider it fixed. As I said I tried to wipe out mysql clean form the system and installed it again. I was following a tutorial on digital ocean that was meant for Ubuntu 14.04 while I was using 16.04. @Solitaire I did not have not root mysql user. at Drew I guess people will keep bumping into problems like this so it would be worth to rewrite my post to make it easier to fix for other people. I just don't know how to do it.