# How can I allow external connections in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to enable external connections in MySQL. I added to my `my.cnf` file: `bind-address` with my specific IP. I also granted all the privileges to root.

when I try to connect from MySQL Workbench, I get this message

[image: Failed to Connect to MySQL at (REDACTED) 3306 with user root. Can't connect to MySQL server on (REDACTED) (10060)]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094726/your-password-does-not-satisfy-the-current-policy-requirements)

Comment: Ok i grant all privileges to root but I can not log in from MysqlWorkbench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* a privileges problem. The error message says a connection to the MySQL server could not be made. Hence it makes no sense to play with grants here. First check if you can "physically" reach the server. For instance ping the target machine and run a telnet command in a terminal to see if the server process is accessible. Firewall settings, other network related problems etc. may block access. Only when you have solved this you can continue with figuring out how to log in (which will give you a different error message, like `Access denied for user blah@foo using password: YES` or similar).

Comment: It was firewall , i opened port 3306

Comment: Ah, glad you found it! Please accept my answer then and if you think it's worth it you can even upvote. Thanks.