# error while reseting mysql root password

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, reset-password

I have mysql installed on ubuntu. I need to log into mysql with root but I cann't remember root password.

so I decided to change root password. I start to do this job by these steps:

1. sudo service mysql stop
2. sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &

at this step I get this error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset or change the MySQL root password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password)

Comment: thank you. that solved my problem!