# MySQL Access denied after typing 'mysql -proot'

Tags: mysql, linux

I am new to MySQL. My issue is, is that after typing `mysql -proot` in the terminal I am receiving this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong. I did create a password. However I don't really know how to put it in, in combo with this command.

I am using CentOS 6 on my server

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444744/596021

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo on the syntax.  You need a space between **proot**.  It should be

```
mysql -p root
```

instead of

```
mysql -proot
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql -proot` this command is telling mysql to use `root` as the password, which I'm assuming is not the password. You need to put a space between the -p switch and the username to be get the interactive password prompt.

```
mysql -p root
```