# What causes Netbeans not to connect to MySQL database properly?

Tags: mysql, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have been googling for hours now and I can't seem to get this thing to work. I am creating a simple Netbeans project app that will allow a user to login and add (store their details on the database) people to the app.

I have to use MySQL database, I have followed all instructions but I just can't connect. Please see screenshots below. I'm also using the downloaded jar. What am I doing wrong? Please help

Netbeans 8.1
MySQL Server 5.6
Windows 10

[image: Basic Propoerties]

[image: Admin Properties]

Answer (score 0):

It says Access Denied. There should be a user in your local Mysql db called root with no password for this to work. Also this user needs to have the correct permissions on this database.

Comment: And how can I add this user, I tried the command `mysql -u root -p mysql` I still get access denied?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password