# How to install mysql again if I forgot my password

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to install mysql and there was no problem until it asked for password and I wrote and it said it was right until it asked for password again for connection and it said that it was wrong i tried to uninstall and install again but it keep asking for my password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: How to reset or change the MySQL root password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/mysql-how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password)

Comment: I have just released how to do it , I have to uninstall everything I am sure this video will be helpful
https://youtu.be/eAOktdUjQTY

Answer (score -1):

as root you can change your password by cmd like
ALTER USER 'yourname'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
you can access your db from anywhere

Comment: This does not help of the OP can not login to the database