# Can't connect to local MySQL server and lost root password

Tags: mysql, forgot-password, mysql-error-2002

I can't connect to a MySQL server, so I stopped MySQL with:

```sh
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
# Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
```

Then, login with root and start MySQL again:

```sh
sudo -s
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
# .... mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
# 2021-05-29T03:01:11.967630Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql...... ended
```

After that I executed:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
# Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/......err'.
# 2021-05-29T03:03:40.507375Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
# 2021-05-29T03:03:40.834556Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/...... ended
# [1]+  Done                    mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

At last I executed:

```sh
mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
mysql -u root
# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I also forgot my **root** password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: How to reset or change the MySQL root password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/mysql-how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password)

Answer (score 0):

H, welcome.

You dont' need to call `mysqld_safe` two times, only one time is necessary. The parameter `--skip-grant-tables` makes any local connection to MySQL happens without password.

The message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

Means that your server isn't listening on default unix socket located on `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

Kill every **mysqld** instance with:

```sh
ps -ef | grep mysql
# copy every id and...
kill <id>
```

Look for any clue in MySQL logs, probrably in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` and then try to start with `mysqld_start --skip-grant-tables`.

Comment: I execute "ps -ef | grep mysql"  and the output was "username          3720    3709  0 05:29 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql"                    so what should I do?

Comment: There is no `mysqld` running. Start it like you already doing and watch the logs.