# MySQL WorkBench root password forgot

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use MySQL Workbench and it is asking me for the root password to connect with localhost, and either it didn't ask me to create this password or I've forgotten it, and I have to use it for a class. What should I do?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: do i type these commands into Terminal?

Comment: It sounds like you are on a Mac. Follow the instructions for UNIX-like systems. Where it shows commands after a prompt like `$>`, those are at the shell prompt in Terminal. Other commands are for the mysql client.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: How to reset or change the MySQL root password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/mysql-how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password)

Answer (score 0):

firstly stop MySQL service on your services area windows:
for this:
1-RUN--> Services
2-find MySQL and stope it

try to edit my.ini  :
find it in MySQL installed place and change the Root Password

start the MySQL service again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).