# Fix MySQL Error: Access Denied for User ‘root’@’localhost’

Tags: mysql

Recently I have a trouble of accessing MySQL database on my macbook. The operating system that I use is MacOS Ventura. I installed MySQL through homebrew by using my terminal. But, when I tried to access the user and the root password, it says

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I tried to use `sudo mysql` but my terminal says

> Password: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).

I also tried using

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_new_password';
```

but it says zsh:

> command not found: ALTER.

Comment: Its becoming my catchphrase, but try using MySQL Workbench.  Its possible to do command line work, but its like calculating numbers in a text file versus using 
Excel to do it.  Download here -> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: I can't access MySQL Workbench too because it required me to enter the root password. I need to reset the root password, could you tell me how to do that on Mac?

Comment: Man I don't know, the problem is that if its easy to do it, then MySQL has ZERO security as people could just reset it and defeat all of its systems.

Comment: Have you try following the steps on the docs? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Also check this link too -->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/mysql-how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password
What version are you using cause 5.* and 8.* have different abilities.